# What's the phonological explanation of Turkish speakers pronouncing "r" as "sh" at the end of the word?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, turkish

I'm a native Turkish speaker and I recently started noticing people around me pronounce "r" as "sh", sometimes [ʒ], when it's at the end of a word. So it's like,

Hayı**r** -> Hayı**ş**

Duva**r** -> Duva**ş**

Kedile**r** -> Kedile**ş**

And they do the same thing when pronouncing words in other languages as well, like in English they'll pronounce "car" as /kɑʃ/, and obviously this isn't an issue among other native Turkish speakers.

Does this have some sort of name? I couldn't get anywhere by googling it.

Comment: I don't have any particular knowledge of Turkish so am not sure if it is genuinely this, but it seems like a variant of final-obstruent devoicing (sometimes referred to by its German name Auslautverhärtung), which is apparently partially present in Turkish

Comment: It's not an uncommon change cross-linguistically. Consider Czech 'ř' (/r̝/) and Polish 'rz' (/ʐ/) which correspond to Russian 'р' (/r/). Conversely, in Old Latin and Old Norse (independently) /s/ -> /z/ -> /r/ in some contexts .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would just call it "final devoicing", but that could be confused with another rule that applies to obstruent stops (*sap ~ sapa* 'stalk' vs. *kap ~ kaba* 'container'). The prior question is whether /r/ at the end of a word is actually identical to /ʃ/ = ‹ş›. At least for some speakers, underlying /ʃ/ is more retracted than final /r/ when it devoices. Another difference is that r-devoicing seems to only apply prepausally but stop-devoicing applies syllable-finally. Therefore there is devoicing of the root consonant before the plural in *ka**p**lar*, but not in *ʃehi**r**ler*. When you have two similar rules, one usually assigns different names, such as "stop devoicing" and "r-devoicing". Because the output of r-devoicing is a unique segment (but the output of stop-devoicing is an already-existing segment), there is little mention of r-devoicing in discussions of phonological processes of Turkish.